# Get real-time data only one way (server to client). Is it worth websockets?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, websocket

I need my website to get real time data from the server (it is for a project in html5, css3, javascript, php, mysql).

Initially I thought about websockets but maybe it is something "beast", since I don't need two-way communication, I just need to capture on the web (in real time without the user doing anything) the values of a mysql field and depending on the themselves do one thing or another in javascript.

My system could have about 1,000 users at a time.

What system do you recommend me? Would you know of any example?

Answer (score 1):

So you basically have a website and you plan on receiving notifications from the server.That to me seems like a continous flow of data from the server to you the client at irregular intervals , and the reasonable way to do it (unless you plan on saving in an IP table your clients) is via websockets.This would be the `push based` approach.
Once you have established connection it remains open and you can get your data continously.

Another option like mentioned above would be to continously pull data from the server (query server for changes) and this could be done with `HTTP`.

So if you choose push based option you could you `Websockets` or you could look at `Server Sent Events`.
For pulling (request-response) you could use `HTTP` or something lighter like `gRPC`.

For more information check the options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet)

Answer (score 0):

The question is not if the communication is one- or two-way but which communication partner initiates a speech act. If the real-time data of your application changes asynchronously and not in a certain rhythm then the server should send updates asynchronously to the webclient. And this is actually one of the standard usages of websockets which cannot be well implemented with HTTP request/response pairs (client would have to poll).